# Ubuntu 20.04 + Macbook 12 + BCM4350 [14e4:43a3] (rev 05) = slow wifi 5Ghz?

Tags: broadcom, macbook

Ubuntu Wifi 5GHz speed 6 MB/s

Macbook Wifi 5Ghz speed 37 MB/s

Ubuntu

```
ssh asus 'dd if=/dev/zero bs=1048576 count=1024 2>/dev/null' | dd of=/dev/null
2033542+65124 records in
2097152+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 174.749 s, 6.1 MB/s
```

Macbook

```
sh asus 'dd if=/dev/zero bs=1048576 count=1024 2>/dev/null' | dd of=/dev/null
2037403+60915 records in
2097152+0 records out
1073741824 bytes transferred in 34.550463 secs (31077494 bytes/sec)
```

Hardware

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a3] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [106b:0168]
    Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
    Kernel modules: brcmfmac
```

[image]